# Django Populate the admin model fields with the data

Tags: python, django, model, django-admin

This is my model.py. I have registered this model with the admin panel. I want to populate my model with data. That data will come from another model and I will perform some calculations on it and put that data in this model. Any help guys. How can I populate my model with data in admin django?

```
class Sectorcapitalratios(models.Model):
    sectorserialnum = models.IntegerField(db_column='SectorSerialNum', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sectorname = models.CharField(db_column='SectorName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    years = models.CharField(db_column='Years', max_length=15)  # Field name made lowercase.
    debttoequityratio = models.FloatField(db_column='DebtToEquityRatio', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    debttocapital = models.FloatField(db_column='DebtToCapital', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    debttototalassets = models.FloatField(db_column='DebtToTotalAssets', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    timestamp =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) #This will create the time

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sectorcapitalratios'
        unique_together = (('sectorserialnum', 'years'),)

    #def __str__(self):
     #   return self.sectorserialnum
```

Admin.py

```
class CapitalratiosResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Capitalratios
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
        import_id_fields = ('ticker','years')

class CapitalratiosAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CapitalratiosResource
    list_display = ('ticker','years','debttoequityratio','debttocapital','debttototalassets')

#Register the Capital Ratios model and admin with the admin
admin.site.register(Capitalratios, CapitalratiosAdmin)
```

Comment: You know, you posted a question without a single question mark. What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I populate model that is registered with admin with my data?